# Error when trying to display an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, httpwebrequest

I have a jQuery code that is supposed to display an image on a button click and to make it disappear on ajax-complete (if there's an ajax request).
The functionality works well in most of my pages, but in a particular page it seems like the request for the image is always unsuccessful - it's the same JS code and same image URL for all of the pages (the image URL is 100% percent valid, it's the same URL in every page).
I attach a print-screen with my chrome network logger, where you can see the image request ion red color (happens only in the particular page:
[image]

I know it could be a little problematic to know what happens, but I would be thankful if you can suggest optional scenarios and I can provide any further information you need about my code.

Thanks from advance!

Comment: Have you checked it on other browsers?

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders
yeah, I checked on firefox. Same problem...

Comment: Does it also happen if you put a static <img> element with this image on that page?

Comment: do you have the image url in a css file (i mean are u invoking the request through a class) or is it an `img` tag that your injecting into the DOM?

Comment: I can see the image if I have the element on the page...
It's an image tag I inject to the DOM.